# How do I set a RecyclerView using GridLayoutManager to match the device screen width?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a `RecyclerView` that I want to always have 3 columns. For some reason the width when using a `GridLayoutManager` seems to be a static width and I'm not sure how to get it to match the screen.

On iOS it is easy as I use a `UICollectionView` and `auto layout` manages that like so:

[image: How width should look.]

How do I get the same result on Android? Here is my `content_symptom_tracker.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bzPrimary"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".SymptomTracker"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_symptom_tracker">

<com.cryptixltd.peterruppert.brainzaps.GridRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/symptomRecycler"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/grid_layout_animation_from_bottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is how I setup the Recycler in the Activity:

```
  recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.symptomRecycler);
    int numberOfColumns = 3;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
    adapter = new SymptomAdapter(this, common_symptoms);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But it gives me this result, the same width no matter the device:

[image]

I don't want to change the size of the icons, just make the spacing of the width match the parent basically.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the GridRecyclerView class, it is a custom class to help with the Grid Animations:

```
  public class GridRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

public GridRecyclerView(Context context) { super(context); }


public GridRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); }


public GridRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { super(context, attrs, defStyle); }

@Override
protected void attachLayoutAnimationParameters(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params,
                                               int index, int count) {
    final LayoutManager layoutManager = getLayoutManager();
    if (getAdapter() != null && layoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager){

        GridLayoutAnimationController.AnimationParameters animationParams =
                (GridLayoutAnimationController.AnimationParameters) params.layoutAnimationParameters;

        if (animationParams == null) {
            // If there are no animation parameters, create new once and attach them to
            // the LayoutParams.
            animationParams = new GridLayoutAnimationController.AnimationParameters();
            params.layoutAnimationParameters = animationParams;
        }

        // Next we are updating the parameters

        // Set the number of items in the RecyclerView and the index of this item
        animationParams.count = count;
        animationParams.index = index;

        // Calculate the number of columns and rows in the grid
        final int columns = ((GridLayoutManager) layoutManager).getSpanCount();
        animationParams.columnsCount = columns;
        animationParams.rowsCount = count / columns;

        // Calculate the column/row position in the grid
        final int invertedIndex = count - 1 - index;
        animationParams.column = columns - 1 - (invertedIndex % columns);
        animationParams.row = animationParams.rowsCount - 1 - invertedIndex / columns;

    } else {
        // Proceed as normal if using another type of LayoutManager
        super.attachLayoutAnimationParameters(child, params, index, count);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hey, have you tried setting the width of the recyclerview to match parent? Like so android:layout_width="match_parent" ?

Comment: @PabiMoloi Yep, It's the same width, just shifted to the left instead.

Comment: Try to set `layout_width="match_parent"` for the items of the `RecyclerView`, and for the `RecyclerView` itself.

Comment: @atarasenko Awesome that did it!

Answer (score 0):

try to set the GridRecyclerView to match constraints.
in your case just make android:layout_width=0dp.

Comment: This just makes the grid shift to the left, The problem seems to be with the GridLayoutManager instead of the actual recyclerView